# Get last characters using $substr

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here’s my query that successfully returns an address:

```
Warehouse.find({}, "address") // -> "123 Cool Street, Sacramento, CA, 95814"
```

How would I get the zip-code out of that using something like substring?

Here’s part of the collection for reference:

```
{
  "price": null,
  "units": [],
  "address": "123 Cool Street, Sacramento, CA, 95814"
}
```

Comment: You can use some aggregation trick here to take out the zip field... Could you post some sample collection.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`$substr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) aggregation subtracting the characters from the last  up to the 5th position of the every `address` field.

```
Warehouse.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "zip": {
      "$substr": [
        "$address",
        {
          "$subtract": [
            { "$strLenCP": "$address" },
            5
          ]
        },
        5
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```